# git: merging changes from multiple branches

Tags: git

I was working on feature branch *fb1* and realized I needed some new features, but they should happen on *master*.  So I branched master to *fb2* and built my features.

Now fb2 needs testing before I merge it into master but I'd like to continue working on fb1 in the mean time.  However I need fb1 to contain the changes on fb2.  They both need to stay up to date with master.

I have tried to merge from both branches, and also like fb1 < fb2 < master, but both of those got ugly fast and I ended up backing out.

I would to learn a new workflow for this if anyone has suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebase fb1 onto fb2:

```
git rebase --onto fb2 master fb1
```

Git will take the commits between master and fb1 and re-creates them on top of fb2 that look the same. Do not rebase already published history and make sure you understand the implications. For first-time rebase users backups are recommended ;)

Comment: ok -- but since i want to continue work on fb1 while fb2 is tested and merged with master, wouldn't i want to `git rebase --onto fb1 master fb2` ?

Comment: You can continue your work on fb1. Just rebase from time to time. After rebasing, fb1 will contain all changes from master and from fb2 (given that master contains no commits that are not contained in fb2 – if that is the case, you have to rebase fb2 onto master first)